# In JavaScript, how can I extract the name of an image file from a long string?

Tags: javascript

Can you help to extract the file name from this string?

```
let str = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/testSite/product/image_folder/Z1-00034-01/1623934721778.jpeg%25253FX-Amz-Algorithm%25253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%252526X-Amz-Date%25253D20210722T050758Z%252526X-Amz-SignedHeaders%25253Dhost%252526X-Amz-Expires%25253D599%252526X-Amz-Credential%25253DAKIA4Z2VUPBRCPYFDP4G%2525252F20210722%2525252Fus-east-1%2525252Fs3%2525252Faws4_request%252526X-Amz-Signature%25253D259df0ed0fd8f827e74c612ff8d87e65e2f2c8d68f75a2f06eb71a84de3847a1%253FX-Amz-Algorithm%253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%2526X";
```

Output should be `1623934721778.jpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always wanted to target a JPEG file, you could use `match` here:

```js
let str = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/testSite/product/image_folder/Z1-00034-01/1623934721778.jpeg%25253FX-Amz-Algorithm%25253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%252526X-Amz-Date%25253D20210722T050758Z%252526X-Amz-SignedHeaders%25253Dhost%252526X-Amz-Expires%25253D599%252526X-Amz-Credential%25253DAKIA4Z2VUPBRCPYFDP4G%2525252F20210722%2525252Fus-east-1%2525252Fs3%2525252Faws4_request%252526X-Amz-Signature%25253D259df0ed0fd8f827e74c612ff8d87e65e2f2c8d68f75a2f06eb71a84de3847a1%253FX-Amz-Algorithm%253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%2526X";
filename = str.match(/\b[^/\s]+\.(?:jpeg|png)/)[0];
console.log(filename);
```

Comment: I want to target any type of extension. The extension would be JPEG/PNG

Comment: Check the updated answer; just check for those two extensions in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're getting a triple escaped URL, but you can fix that like this:

```js
let str = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/testSite/product/image_folder/Z1-00034-01/1623934721778.jpeg%25253FX-Amz-Algorithm%25253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%252526X-Amz-Date%25253D20210722T050758Z%252526X-Amz-SignedHeaders%25253Dhost%252526X-Amz-Expires%25253D599%252526X-Amz-Credential%25253DAKIA4Z2VUPBRCPYFDP4G%2525252F20210722%2525252Fus-east-1%2525252Fs3%2525252Faws4_request%252526X-Amz-Signature%25253D259df0ed0fd8f827e74c612ff8d87e65e2f2c8d68f75a2f06eb71a84de3847a1%253FX-Amz-Algorithm%253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%2526X";
const url = new URL(unescape(unescape(unescape(str))));
const filename = url.pathname.split('/').pop();
console.log(filename)
```

Comment: May I know how do you know this is triple escaped? Just curious.

Comment: @ikhvjs - because URL "search" is usually separated by `?` ... escaped that's `%3D` - escape that you get `%253D` and escape that you get `%25253D` .... similarly with `&` = `%26` -> `%2526` -> `%252526` ... so, run `unescape` 3 times on that string and you get something that looks like a **valid** URL - I've seen escaped enough to recognise it, I've even seen double escaped - this is my first triple though

Comment: @Bravo Search? Do you mean the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)?

Comment: @Ivar - yes - no idea why I call it `search` ... oh, wait, that's because a URL is made up of  `protocol//host:port/pathname?search#hash` - so, guess I used the correct term with respect to the parts of an URL - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68480889/why-do-people-escape-a-uri-tribble-times

Comment: The new URL(unescape(str)) works perfectly. However, according to the Mozilla documentation, the new Url is only partially supported by Safari on iOS. Is this code executable in the iOS Mobile APP?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: @ChandraMouli, you can have a look of https://caniuse.com/?search=URL

Comment: that's really odd what they put in MDN - some "issue" with "In Safari 14 and earlier" - but doesn't explain partial support ... possibly full support in 15 and later? oh right ... 14 is the current version .... well, just don't *call the URL constructor with a base URL whose value is undefined* and you'll be golden

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/testSite/product/image_folder/Z1-00034-01/1623934721778.jpeg%25253FX-Amz-Algorithm%25253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%252526X-Amz-Date%25253D20210722T050758Z%252526X-Amz-SignedHeaders%25253Dhost%252526X-Amz-Expires%25253D599%252526X-Amz-Credential%25253DAKIA4Z2VUPBRCPYFDP4G%2525252F20210722%2525252Fus-east-1%2525252Fs3%2525252Faws4_request%252526X-Amz-Signature%25253D259df0ed0fd8f827e74c612ff8d87e65e2f2c8d68f75a2f06eb71a84de3847a1%253FX-Amz-Algorithm%253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%2526X";
var patt1 = /[\w&.-]+\.([0-9a-z]+)(?:[\?#%]|$)/i;
var matches= str.match(patt1);
let filename = matches[0].split(".")[0] + '.' +matches[1]
console.log(matches)
console.log(filename)
//EDIT
var patt2 = /([\w&.-]+)\.([0-9a-z]+)(?:[\?#%]|$)/i;
var matches= str.match(patt2);
let filename2 = matches[1] + '.' +matches[2]
console.log(matches)
console.log(filename2)
```

1. `[\w&.-]` - Matches FileName. If you change `[\w&.-] to [/\/\w&.-]` it will match all characters except https://
2. `[0-9a-z]` - This one matches extension
3. `[\?#%]` - Here you can add special characters to be removed
4. $ symbol will match last words
5. /i - ignore case in the given string
6. `([\w&.-]+) and ([0-9a-z]+)` will match filename and extension seperate