# Why do people escape a URI three times?

Tags: javascript, escaping, uri

I ask this question because I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68480488/14032355)  and I am curious why people do that.

For example, we have a URI below which is escaped 3 times. Why do people need to escape it 3 times instead of 1 time only? Is there any reason behind this?

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/testSite/product/image_folder/Z1-00034-01/1623934721778.jpeg%25253FX-Amz-Algorithm%25253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%252526X-Amz-Date%25253D20210722T050758Z%252526X-Amz-SignedHeaders%25253Dhost%252526X-Amz-Expires%25253D599%252526X-Amz-Credential%25253DAKIA4Z2VUPBRCPYFDP4G%2525252F20210722%2525252Fus-east-1%2525252Fs3%2525252Faws4_request%252526X-Amz-Signature%25253D259df0ed0fd8f827e74c612ff8d87e65e2f2c8d68f75a2f06eb71a84de3847a1%253FX-Amz-Algorithm%253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%2526X`

after unescape 3 times, we have

```js
const str = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test/testSite/product/image_folder/Z1-00034-01/1623934721778.jpeg%25253FX-Amz-Algorithm%25253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%252526X-Amz-Date%25253D20210722T050758Z%252526X-Amz-SignedHeaders%25253Dhost%252526X-Amz-Expires%25253D599%252526X-Amz-Credential%25253DAKIA4Z2VUPBRCPYFDP4G%2525252F20210722%2525252Fus-east-1%2525252Fs3%2525252Faws4_request%252526X-Amz-Signature%25253D259df0ed0fd8f827e74c612ff8d87e65e2f2c8d68f75a2f06eb71a84de3847a1%253FX-Amz-Algorithm%253DAWS4-HMAC-SHA256%2526X";

const o = unescape(unescape(unescape(str)));

console.log(o);
```

Maybe it is obvious to other people, but I don't know.

Comment: technically that's quadruple escaped (you can see the `%2F` which are `/`) - but single escaped values in the URL search string are normal (expected) ... why three more times? I suspect a URL is passed from one API to another escaping the whole URL every time. That or poor/lazy coding :p

Comment: Before you get the params .There are four people eg A ->B-> C-> D .  and You are the last . Each one  encode the url. so that's what you got .

Comment: @Bravo "security by obscurity", maybe? ;-)